# Is there a swing map of 2017 Senate and 2016 President in Alabama?

Tags: united-states, election, statistics, reference-request, data-sources

I want to see a picture of a county-level swing map of the 2017 Senate election for Alabama relative to the 2016 presidential election. This is to see how many points the election swung in Democrat candidate Doug Jones's favor because of the sexual assault allegations against his opponent, Roy Moore.

Comment: Your goal is not practical. While we could definitely make a map of how the vote in each county differed between 2016 and 2017, it wouldn't tell you anything about the effect of "sexual assault allegations". There are countless factors that affected that election – picking out one from this kind of data is impossible. Also, credible sexual assault allegations are one of the main things that Trump and Moore had in common, so I think you'd need to dig a lot deeper to pick out that effect.

Comment: No. I want to see the map county by county

Answer (score 4):

This is relatively easy to visualise using the county-level results from both the [2016 Presidential Election](https://www.sos.alabama.gov/sites/default/files/voter-pdfs/2016/2016-Official-General-Election-Results-Certified-2016-11-29.pdf) and the [2017 Special Senate Election](https://www.sos.alabama.gov/sites/default/files/voter-pdfs/2017%20Official%20General%20Election%20Results%20with%20Write-In%20Appendix%20-%202017-12-28.pdf). That being said, the use of this swing alone to quantify the influence of Roy Moore's sexual assault allegations on the election would be an oversimplification at best.

Nevertheless, no county in Alabama returned a lower percentage of Democratic votes in the 2017 election than in the 2016 election. The county with the lowest Democrat swing was Macon County, with an increase from 82.78% to 88.14%, a swing of 5.36%, while the county with the highest Democrat swing was Lee County, with an increase from 35.87% to 57.61%, a swing of 21.74%. The average swing was 11.04%, while the median swing was 10.76%.

The map below was created using geopandas & a shapefile from the Alabama Oil & Gas Board, available [here](https://www.gsa.state.al.us/ogb/gisdata).

[image: Map]

Comment: "easy to visualise"...

Comment: Nice answer. Did you make that map, or did you find it somewhere? Since we get these kinds of questions pretty often, if there's a more general source, it might make sense to advertise that

Comment: @divibisan It's created using a shapefile from the Alabama Oil & Gas board, of all places. I'll add a link to the post.

Comment: Very nice work but I would emphasise the "oversimplification at best".